# How do you make a movie clip, clickable after just becoming visible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

So I have a movie clip called signInBtn and one called signOutBtn
initially,

```
signOutBtn.visible = false;
```

but when a user signs in

```
signInBtn.visible = false;
signOutBtn.visible = true;
```

But after I do that, I can't click the signOut movieclip. I thought it might be because the signOutBtn was under the invisible signInBtn but that is not the case.

Comment: Are you using Event.CLICK on the MovieClip?

Comment: you should use one button that changes labels and targets different events based on the label rather than managing 2 different buttons.

Comment: yeah I know i should make one button with differnt labels but I just need this all done very quickly as it is an assignment that is due in 5 hours from now. I will go back and do everything perfect later for my own amusement but for now I need a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Edit

```
 signout works when it is in a different position to sign in but when it is in 
 the same position as signin it cant be clicked. when the sign out button is half 
 over the same position as the signin button, half the signout button works and 
 half doesnt
```

If you have a MovieClip or a Sprite on top of another, the mouse event will be screened, there are ways around that though. In any case , in your example, simply disable a button when you don't need it

```
     signInBtn.visible = false;
     signInBtn.mouseEnabled = false;

     signOutBtn.visible = true;
```

End of Edit

There's no apparent reason why signOutBtn shouldn't be clickable after its visibility has been toggled. The error is somewhere else.

Make sure both buttons are clickable before changing their visibility.

Have you added event listeners to both buttons, are you removing event listeners after the event has been fired?

Comment: they both have event listeners and they are both clickable

Comment: signout works when it is in a different position to sign in but when it is in the same position as signin it cant be clicked. when the sign out button is half over the same position as the signin button, half the signout button works and half doesnt

Comment: then you may have to show some code. as i said before , changing visibility won't affect whether a button is clickable or not. we need to know more about your implementation...

Answer (score 0):

```
package
{ 
import fl.controls.Button;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Test extends Sprite
{
private static const SIGN_IN:String = "Sign In";
private static const SIGN_OUT:String = "Sign Out";

private var button:Button;

public function Test()
     {
     button = new Button();
     button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickEventListener);
     button.label = SIGN_IN;

     addChild(button);
     }

private function buttonClickEventListener(evt:MouseEvent):void
     {
     switch (button.label)
            {
            case SIGN_IN:   button.label = SIGN_OUT;
                            trace("Signed in");
                            break;

            case SIGN_OUT:  button.label = SIGN_IN;
                            trace("Signed out");
            }
      }
}
}
```